# JQuery Visual Diff Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

is there a JQuery visual diff plugin that anybody knows about. Something like you would see on GitHub, BitBucket, or any standard source control site?

I have found this https://github.com/cemerick/jsdifflib and it looks pretty good, but wonder if there are more out there like it.

Thank You.

Comment: The link for jsdifflib is broken, anyone know if it is still around?

Comment: Found the updated link: https://github.com/cemerick/jsdifflib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should consider doing a home made plugin, to do the Visual thing.

There is a jquery plugin which allow you to do $diff comparison like [this one](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-diff) :

By using this you get a usable collection of elements:

```
$.diff(obj1, obj2) return  {mod: ..., add: ..., del: ...}
```

You could use jsfiddle to prototype your own plugin (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 12):

This is long since done, but for posterity:

https://github.com/arnab/jQuery.PrettyTextDiff

Comment: This is actually a wrapper over Google's google-diff-match-patch. https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/

Answer (score 2):

https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/ is Google's library for diff.  They have implementation for Java, JavaScript, Dart, C++, C#, Objective C, Lua and Python.

I have used it, its pretty neat and powerful.