# Is there jQuery plugin to compare differences in two different text strings?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, text-comparison

I need compare differences in two different versions of same text like in Wikipedia or Stackoverflow, and I would like to know if there is jQuery plugin for this kind of purpose.

Comment: What kind of comparison do you want to achieve? What is your goal? Are you looking for something like http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQueryCompare?

Comment: User edits text and when user saves changes, new version is saved. Some times user might want to compare what was changed between versions, so  I wanted to add this version comparsion util to help users. Only thing that matters is that its easy to use for user.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825443/jquery-visual-diff-plugin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

look on

http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/

the demo in

http://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/svn/trunk/demos/demo_diff.html

Comment: I recommend Google's diff_match_patch too. It's an awesome library that you can tweak in lots of ways. The API is a little bit of a pain - so I wrote a jQuery library to wrap the calls: https://github.com/arnab/jQuery.PrettyTextDiff/