# Is there a JQuery plugin which compares two strings and highlights the differences

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know of a JQuery plugin which compares two strings and highlights the differences.  I've tried searching but although there is stuff out there I can't find a JQuery specific one.  An example of a javascript one which does what I want is

[Javascript Diff Algorithm](http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/)

The problem with this one is that I want to implement it on a number of different strings at once (1 on each row of a table) which is why I wanted a Jquery one so I could use JQuerys each selector methods

Comment: i can't see why you need specific jquery because it is javascript so it **is** compatible. Besides, i don't understand your `different strings at once` >> how would you want the script to behave?

Comment: Agree with @JMax. And, why can't you use the javascript diff alogrithm **with** jquery's `each`?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825443/jquery-visual-diff-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't be looking for a jQuery plugin in your case. jQuery is a framework that helps handling the DOM changes and more, but there are not many string functions in jQuery.

Another one found through Google does almost the same as the one you reference:
http://www.daftlogic.com/sandbox-javascript-compare-differences-between-strings.htm

**edit**
It seems like the above mentioned script is the same one used by John Resig
thanks for pointing that out danishgoel **end edit**

Your problem is that you want it to run over a list of items in a table?
You would not need jQuery for the actual check on differences, but you can use a `for` loop around it, or a jQuery `each` call around it.

Like this HTML:

```
<ul id='sentences'>
    <li>sentence 1</li>
    <li>sentence 2</li>
    <li>sentence 3</li>
</ul>
```

and this JavaScript:

```
var default = "my sentence";
$('#sentences li').each(function(){
    var li = $(this);
    var result = $('<div/>').html( diffString( default, li.text() ) );
    li.append(result);
});
```

As you can see, here you use the jQuery `each` on a jQuery selector but you ask a regular JavaScript function. No need for a jQuery plugin to do exactly the same.

Comment: this uses the same javascript algorithm that John posted in his question.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [Javascript Diff Algorithm](http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/).
Check a demo at : http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/Z3CRA/1/.

Instead of calling and aplying the function directly :

```
document.body.innerHTML = diffString(
   "The red brown fox jumped over the rolling log.",
   "The brown spotted fox leaped over the rolling log"
);
```

You can wrap it into a jquery plugin :

```
$.fn.pluginName = function(newValue){
    return this.each(function(){
        $(this).html(
            diffString(
                $(this).text(),
                newValue
            )
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: This is a link to an answer, not an answer.

Answer (score -4):

Searched on google and got this. [jQueryCompare](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQueryCompare).

Have a look at it.

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: Link does not exist. 404!