# How can I get the part of the URL that is getting changed whenever I clicked on some link?

Tags: c#, javascript

My home page is :

```
http://localhost:8089/AFPWeb4.0/Project/ProjectList.aspx?StartPage=1
```

I have a link ProjectListInProjectGroups . When a user clicks on that link, my URL is changed to

```
http://localhost:8089/AFPWeb4.0/ProjectListInProjectGroups.aspx?
```

How can I get part of the URL that is changed ? 
I need this value ProjectListInProjectGroups. I want to get this value in a ascx page.

Can someone help on this?

Comment: In JS you can use document.referrer to get the previous URL.  and please have a look at this post to compare strings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470652/is-there-a-jquery-plugin-which-compares-two-strings-and-highlights-the-differenc it should help you..

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the current URL to the next page as a parameter and then you can find the difference between the two URLs using string operations.

Answer (score 0):

If in your console you type window.location.pathname you would get the route after host name.

In console just type window.location and you can see what properties that has.