# javascript string different

Tags: jquery, diff

```
var a = "asdf";
var b = "asdf\nqwer"

//example
function diff(a,b){
    return {add: "qwer"}
}

var c = "aaaa";
var d = "aa";
function diff(c,d){
    return {del: "aa"}
}
```

I want to get object like above result value.
Is there any other plug-in or modules that gives the value of these results?

Also, I have been know that python has these module or plug-in named 'difflib'.
Like this, can I find modules or plugin above jquery and javascript?

Comment: sorry what should the desired output

Comment: Could you clarify what the result value is? Do you mean `return {del: "aa"}` and `return {add: qwer}`? If so, I _think_ SO doesn't welcome asking for code. (I'm probably wrong)

Comment: Please refer to the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)to know how to ask a question.

Comment: may be http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hM58h/1/ or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hM58h/2/

Comment: I just saw... the tag "diff" is used inappropriately. It is for file differences and is usually more complex than comparing strings.

Comment: Like hg mercurial, i want to get the result add, del case by case.

Comment: Wait why is the tag jquery? Are you using it?

Comment: Btw minjiLee, you should @ names so people see you. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470652/is-there-a-jquery-plugin-which-compares-two-strings-and-highlights-the-differenc

Answer (score 0):

I think you are simply searching for substr()

```
var a = "asdf";
var b = "asdf\nqwer"
b.substr(a.length);

output: "qwer"


output: "aa"
var c = "aaaa";
var d = "aa";
c.substr(d.length);

output: "aa"
```