# insert html elements into string of text to match another string of html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, compare

have two files pdf and html, reading the files in as strings of plain text (after extracting text from pdf) and html and now trying to make plain text have same html tags as html string. Then to compare them to find differences

Final Edit of simple example not currently working

```
var text1="here is example text";

var text2="<html><body><div>here is another <span>example</span> text</div></body></html>";

var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = text2;
var text = div.textContent || div.innerText || "";

var content=  text.split(" ");
var alltags=text2.match(/<.+?>/g);
var pdfwords=text1.split(" ");
var output="";
for(var j=0; j<alltags.length; j++){
   for(i=0; i<pdfwords.length; i++){
      if(pdfwords[i]===content[j]){

         output+=alltags[i]+pdfwords[i];
      }
    }
}

document.write(output);
```

output should be

```
"<html><body><div>here is another<span>example</span> text</div></body></html>"
```

diff these two strings output and text2 shows difference as "another" is inserted

Comment: why don't you strip html tags and just compare plain text?

Comment: That does not work because pdf text placement can be lines away from html text so it does not match, I already tried that and html text has a extra section as well

Comment: The html provided contains large amount of css, javascript tags, inline javascript, meta tag and html comment. So if you want to keep them and compare, that is impossible to create some automatic algorithm to do it. So first, you have to specify what exactly you want compare, Because comparing `<script language="JavaScript" src="./javatest_files/metrics_group1.js"></script>` is meaningless in this situation

Comment: Ignore the script tags, only focus on markup so html tags and inline css

Comment: What is the extra section you mentioned in you tried strip tags and comparing

Comment: lines can move up or down so wont be in same order one pdf text is extracted and there is a extra section added in the beginning of the html file. So need markup to compare better

Comment: The extra section is either the Title in `<head>` tag, `description` in `<head>` tag or a few links in front of your paragraph such as `<a class="jvl0" href="https://java.com/" title="java.com">Java.com</a>` , by removing the tags, the `Java.com` will be preserved but I don't think you really need it. If you mean the extra space left there, you can use regex to replace new lines, multiple space with one single space. I am assuming the content you actually want to compare is within the '<div class="jvc0w2"> </div>'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112103/discussion-between-ak0101-and-lhrec-106).

Comment: Can you clarify the problem further? Do you just want to see if the text from both matches, and if so, change the plain string to be exactly the same as the HTML string?

Comment: sure, the problem is I want to match the text from the pdf and html files and find differences. So right now I want to change the plain text string to be the same as html string as in the tags will wrap around the same text for the most part.

Comment: Are they guaranteed to be the same text, at least in the `<body>`? Or are only certain parts of the text going to be the same?

Comment: they will be the same for about 95% of the text. Certain parts will definitely be the same.

Comment: Javascript Diff Algorithm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470652/is-there-a-jquery-plugin-which-compares-two-strings-and-highlights-the-differenc

Answer (score 7):

This is a simple solution of what you want, it is a dynamic solution as it will handle any tags found and compare only the text content. The `findDiff()` will find the difference and call the callback function with the output and a array of different words as parameters.

JSFiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/9svuc7om/18/](https://jsfiddle.net/9svuc7om/5/)

```
/**
 * Parse and construct an Array of PDF text tokens
 * @params {string} text   The PDF text to be parsed
 * @return {object}         The parsed Array of tokens
 */
function parsePDFText(text) {
    var token = text.split(' ');
    for (var i=0,l=token.length; i<l; i++) {
        // remove token of first space and consecutive space
        if (token[i] == '') {
            token.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    return token;
}

/**
 * Return the minimum indexOf among all the arguments
 * @params {...number} index  The indexOf
 * @return {number}           The minimum indexOf, -1 if all arguments are -1
 */
function findMinIndex() {
    var min;
    for (var i = 0, l = arguments.length; i < l; i++) {
        // indexOf() returns -1 if not found
        if (arguments[i] === -1) {
            continue;
        }
        if (typeof min === 'undefined' || arguments[i] < min) {
            min = arguments[i];
        }
    }
    return min || -1;
}

/**
 * Parse and construct an Array of HTML tokens
 * @params {string} text   The HTML text to be parsed
 * @return {object}       The parsed Array of tokens
 */
function parseHTMLText(text) {
    var currentIndex = 0,
        tl = text.length,
        tokens = [],
        token, firstChar, endPos;
    while (currentIndex < tl) {
        // determine the next token type
        firstChar = text.charAt(currentIndex);
        if (firstChar == '<') {
            // a tag
            // find the position of closing tag, assume all tags are well formed
            endPos = text.indexOf('>', currentIndex + 1) + 1;
            token = {
                type: 'tag',
                content: text.slice(currentIndex, endPos), 
                valid: true
            }
            currentIndex = endPos;
        } else if (firstChar == ' ') {
            // a space
            token = {
                type: 'space', 
                content: ' ', 
                valid: true
            }
            currentIndex++;
        } else {
            // a character, possibliy part of a word
            // find the end of the word
            // assume a word is delimitered either by tags or space
            endPos = findMinIndex(text.indexOf('<', currentIndex), text.indexOf(' ', currentIndex));
            // endPos is `-1` if there are not delimiter anymore, end of string reached
            if (endPos === -1) {
                endPos = tl;
            }
            token = {
                type: 'text',
                content: text.slice(currentIndex, endPos), 
                valid: true
            }
            currentIndex = endPos;
        }
        tokens.push(token);
    }
    return tokens;
}

/**
 * Find the difference between pdf text and html text and pass the output and differenc to a callback function
 * @params {string} pdfText     The pdf text
 * @params {string} htmlText    The html text
 * @params {function} callback  The callback function
 */
function findDiff(pdfText, htmlText, callback) {
    var output = '', // the final output
        diff = [], // the array of different words
        pdfTokens = parsePDFText(pdfText),
        htmlTokens = parseHTMLText(htmlText), 
        j=0, hl=htmlTokens.length;
    // the pdf text is the reference point, i.e. all the words in pdf text should always be present in html text as well
    for (var i=0,pl=pdfTokens.length; i<pl; i++) {
        // find the first occurrence of the pdf text
        for(; j<hl; j++) {
            if (htmlTokens[j].type != 'text') {
                // exclude comparison to non-text
                continue;
            }
            // check if the two text matches
            if (htmlTokens[j].content == pdfTokens[i]) {
                // a match is found
                j++;
                break;
            } else {
                // push the different html token into `diff` array
                diff.push(htmlTokens[j].content);
                // set the `valid` field of token to false
                htmlTokens[j].valid = false;
            }
        }
    }
    // invalidate the rest of the html text
    for(; j<hl; j++) {
        if (htmlTokens[j].type == 'text') {
            htmlTokens[j].valid = false;
        }
    }
    // concat the final string to output
    for (j=0; j<hl; j++) {
        if (htmlTokens[j].valid) {
            output += htmlTokens[j].content;
        }
    }
    callback(output, diff);
}
```

And you can call the function by using

```
findDiff(text1, text2, function(output, diff) {
    console.log(output);
    console.log(diff);
});
```

However, there are some limitations in this solution

1. It assumes all the content in pdf are present in the HTML text
2. It only handles `<>` and space, if there are other possible delimiter, e.g. tabs, extra code is needed
3. It assumes all tags are well-formed, and there will not be closing tags in between text content(if you need you should use `&gt;` `&lt;` instead)
4. The function is a simplified solution and is not fully tested. You cannot expect any warranty from it and some adaptations is needed. I would suggest providing only the content inside `body` or even a narrower range instead of the whole HTML file (if in your case it is possible) because there will be too much variations in the content of a HTML file.

Comment: Thanks, I think because of limitations I could actually not compare them and just get the PDF text in html but that is not working for me

Comment: I am just getting a lot of white space for the output empty html tags

Comment: not working for simple example in fiddle says everything is different  https://jsfiddle.net/9svuc7om/17/ and wont even display output

Comment: @AK0101 Sorry, there is bug in the`parsePDFToken()` in which I miss the cases when the first character is space and/or there is consecutive space. I have revised and produced a new version: [https://jsfiddle.net/9svuc7om/18/](https://jsfiddle.net/9svuc7om/18/)

Comment: Im still getting half the output in your demo example and lots of differences. The output stops at "Why download"

Comment: @AK0101 I am studying the new example text you have given, and you will see the html stopped at `<h3>Why download Java Today?</h3>` because `Today?` is considered a single word while in your PDF it is `Why download Java?`. So `Today?` does not match with `Java?` and the comparison consider all the remaining text different. As I mentioned in 2nd point in the limitations, you will have to add more delimiter like symbols in this case to make the parse more intelligent. I am giving you a simplified `findDiff()` as a starting point.

Comment: ok thanks, yeah "today" was one of the differences I added to test but did not consider "?". Also I am thinking instead of trying to find differences I can just convert the pdf into html using the output which will have the pdf text in html tags. That way dont have to worry about differences.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is

```
var s="Hello everyone on stackoverflow"
var s_split = s.split(' ');
var y = '<html><head></head><body><div>' + s_split[0] + '<span>' + s_split[1] + '</span>' + s_split[2]+' ' + s_split[3] + '</div></body></html>';
```

Check the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v56mv6y1/)

Comment: It doesn't really find the difference and marks it.

Comment: The original question has been modified for a few times. and He deleted the original HTML part he wanted to modify the pdf to. If you really wanted to know the original HTML and the difference, you can see the chatroom we discussed  here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112103/discussion-between-ak0101-and-lhrec-106. You will notice how impossible it was to add HTML tags to it. I convinced him to strip out all unnecessary html tags like <javascript> <style> <form> etc.

Answer (score 5):

Why not simply strip the html tags and compare the text.

```
var s = "Hello everyone on stackoverflow";

var y = "<html><head><head><body><div>Hello<span>everyone</span>on stackoverflow</div></body></html>";

//using regular expressions match HTML tags and replace them with empty string. Make sure to trim the output so that the extra whitespaces at either end are removed.
var z = y.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, ' ').trim();

//compare if the stripped string matches the other string.
if(z == s) {
    s = y;  
}
alert(s);
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ffffpgyh/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have to wrap specific word or text then search and replace it something like this:

```
var f = "Hello everyone on stackoverflow";
var o = "Hello";
var e = "everyone on";
var s = "stackoverflow";

if (f.indexOf(e) >= 0) {
    var h = f.replace(e,"<strong>"+e+"</strong>");
}else{
    var h = f;
}
if (h.indexOf(s) >= 0){
    var h = h.replace(s,"<em>"+s+"</em>");
}
if (h.indexOf(o) >= 0){
    var h = h.replace(o,"<u>"+o+"</u>");
}

$('body').append('<div>'+h+'</div>');
```

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/jwqrgsL1/1/